# Creating binary variables with mutiple indices in gurobi

Tags: python, variables, optimization, gurobi

I am pretty new to Python and Gurobi. I want to add a binary variable for several "dimensions":

```
A = [1,2,3,4]
B = [1,2,3,4]
C = [1,2,3,4,5]
D = [1,2,3]
```

I need the binary variable x with indices A,B,C,D.

I am not sure how to use the command:

```
m.addVars()
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how you create variables from a given index list:

```
import gurobipy as gp

A = [1,2,3,4]
model = gp.Model()
variables = model.addVars(A, name='A', vtype='B')
```

After calling `model.update()`, you see these variable names/types:

```
{1: <gurobi.Var A[1]>,
 2: <gurobi.Var A[2]>,
 3: <gurobi.Var A[3]>,
 4: <gurobi.Var A[4]>}
```

This is also explained in the [documentation](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.0/refman/py_model_addvars.html). You simply repeat this process for the other lists `B`, `C`, and `D`.

**EDIT**

Another alternative to combine all indices into one variable structure is the following:

```
A = [1,2,3,4]
B = [1,2]
C = [1,2,3]
model = gp.Model()
variables = model.addVars(A, B, C, vtype='B')
```

You would access these variables like this:

```
variables[1,2,1]
```

Comment: Thanks! By using this approach I can access a specific variable by print(variables[1,2,3,4]). What do I need to change if I want to access a variable like this: print(variables[1][2][3][4])?